# How to express one constraint as a function of another with sum in FreeCAD

Tags: cad

I have one named constraint, R1, and now I want to define another constraint as R1-5. How can this be done? I been reading [here](https://wiki.freecadweb.org/Expressions) and I manage to make it work with product and division but not sum or subtraction:

[image: Screenshot working]

[image: Screenshot fail]

As seen, I get an error when I try to use `+` or `-` operators. I am using FreeCAD 0.20.1 in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is add units for the number!
i.e. -5mm